# Range of min-height and max-height with their zoom level

Tags: html, css, zooming

The @media tag helps in defining the zoom level of the screen.
For example,

```
@media(min-width:1165px) and (max-width:1366px){
    .subheader
    {
        position:fixed;
        top:8.5%;
        left:0%;
        background-color:;
    }
    .notices
    {
        margin-top:8%;
        margin-left:22%;
    }
}
```

The range of 1165px to 1366px is executed when the zoom level is approximately 125%. So can anyone tell me the exact ranges for all the zoom levels like 25%, 33%, 50%, 75%, 90%, 100%, 125%, 150%, 175%, 200%, 250%, 300%, 400% and 500%.
I tried googling it but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: That depends on the window size, obviously. Logical pixel size = actual pixel size / zoom level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented on the chrome browser and this is what I came up with,

```
@media (min-width:273px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:red;
    }
}

@media (min-width:274px) and (max-width:341px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:orange;
    }
}

@media (min-width:342px) and (max-width:455px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:green;
    }
}

@media (min-width:456px) and (max-width:546px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:yellow;
    }
}

@media (min-width:547px) and (max-width:683px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:grey;
    }
}

@media (min-width:684px) and (max-width:781px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:white;
    }
}

@media (min-width:782px) and (max-width:911px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:black;
    }
}

@media (min-width:912px) and (max-width:1093px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:aqua;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1094) and (max-width:1242px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:tan;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1243px) and (max-width:1366px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:blue;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1367px) and (max-width:1517px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:violet;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1518px) and (max-width:1821px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:indigo;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1822px) and (max-width:2051px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:purple;
    }
}

@media (min-width:2052px) and (max-width:2732px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:magenta;
    }
}

@media (min-width:2733px) and (max-width:4102px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:azure;
    }
}

@media (min-width:4103px) and (max-width:5464px)
{
    .subheader
    {
        background-color:brown;
    }
}
```

The ranges are from 25% to 500% as mentioned in the question